# Filter element in array of doubles

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array of double

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 ... 10.0
```

Output

```
filter(3,7)  should produce 3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0

filter(5,7.5) should produce 5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0

filter(6.6,6.7) should produce 6.0,7.0
```

based on a `filter` method

```
public List<Double> filter(double start, double end){
    List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0);
    List<Double> resultList = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

     //search in list for elements such that it includes the lower bounds and upper bound of search
     //i.e. 6.6 should also include 6.0 and 7.0 from the array. 


   return resultList;

}
```

This seems simple but I have not been able to come up with a solution that I am happy with, hence the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 3.0 and 8.0 aren't between 3.6 and 7.8.

Comment: Can you show us a solution you tried & explain the problems you were having with it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by filter? just print the output? create a new array? remove matching values from the existing array? As Qoop point out, your "output" is not helpful...

Comment: As well as showing your best effort so far, please indicate why you are not happy with it.

Comment: One straightforward solution would be to iterate over the array and add the number to a new list if it is within the specified range.

Comment: @Reimeus the solution is very long and tiring for loops hence I have not posted it here I tried using Apache Ranges but it did not help in all the scenarios

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  yes it seems simple but gets complicated coz of the upperbound and lower bound factors

Comment: @user1828324 In what way does it get complicated? Iterate over the array and add each number you find to the new list if and only if it is within the desired bounds. If there is a specific part of that you don't know how to do, just ask. Unless of course I have misunderstood you, in which case you might want to update your question to be clearer.

Comment: @IskarJarak I think the input is simply the two bounds, not an array.

Comment: @jma127 Yeah, that's one possibility, but the question is totally not clear on that. Especially since the word filter is involved and he says 'given an array'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-loop solution should be the easiest, as you can use the `Math.floor` function to get the start of your desired list:

```
for (double d = Math.floor(start); d <= Math.ceil(end); d += 1.0)
    list.add(d);
```

Comment: This solution does not produce the desired result

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is your desired result? If it's to print all integers in the range [start, end], this should work.

Comment: It does on my machine: what is the result on yours?

Comment: Maybe he wants `floor()` on the lower bound and `ceil()` on the upper bound? That would give (3.6,7.8)=>(3.0,...,8.0).

Comment: That would make sense: the 'desired output' in the question was a bit unclear. Edited the answer.

Comment: You answer says "you can use the `Math.ceil` function to get the start of your desired list" despite using `floor();` for the start... you might want to fix that too ;)

Comment: Sorry guys this is my first time on stackoverflow. thanks for your patience

Comment: @user1828324 If the updated answer produces the desired result, then you should select the hollow tickbox by it to accept jma127's answer.

Comment: Sorry @jma127 my Bad.. Can you alter your code to search the array??

Comment: It would be nice if you could be a bit more specific.

Comment: @jma127 modified the original post does that help?

Comment: You really should be trying out looping/iteration by yourself, as it'll help you later on. However, I'll try to point you in the right direction. The for-each loop has the syntax `for (Object o : list)`. So, what you could do is `for (Double d : list)` and then for each double d, do the greater-than-floor and less-than-ceil check described above to decide whether to add it to `resultList`.

Comment: @jma127 thanks for that sometimes just asking other helps ... I was going down wrong direction with this ... that for helping me clear my head :)